# Code to write appended data into xlsx rows without overwrite under a looping environment

Tags: python, loops

I am going to write appended data into xlsx rows without overwrite under a looping environment.  Unfortunately not working.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook


t=0
while t <= 3:

    filename = "myfile.xlsx"
    d1 = 'ID:001'
    d2 = 'ID:002'
    d3 = 'ID:003'
    new_row = [(d1), (d2), (d3)]

    try:
        wb = load_workbook(filename)
        ws = wb.worksheets[0]
    except FileNotFoundError:
        headers_column = ['Header 1', 'Header 2', 'Header 3']
        wb = Workbook()
        ws = wb.active
        ws.append(headers_row)

    ws.append(new_row)
    wb.save(filename)
    wb.save.close()

    t = t + 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have 2 errors:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook   

t=0
while t <= 3:

    filename = "myfile.xlsx"
    d1 = 'ID:001'
    d2 = 'ID:002'
    d3 = 'ID:003'
    new_row = [(d1), (d2), (d3)]

    try:
        wb = load_workbook(filename)
        ws = wb.worksheets[0]
    except FileNotFoundError:
        headers_row = ['Header 1', 'Header 2', 'Header 3']
        wb = Workbook()
        ws = wb.active
        ws.append(headers_row)

    ws.append(new_row)
    wb.save(filename)
    wb.close()

    t = t + 1
```

you had a typo: headers_column should be headers_row.

and you had wb.save.close() but it should only be wb.close()

Comment: Thanks for your fast and great support. It is really useful.

Comment: @陳韋仲 if it solved your question please accept the answer, so that other know the question is already answered and if someone has a similar problem knows that this is the solution.